# Lock the width of a textbox

Tags: html, css, forms, textbox, locking

Is it possible to lock the width of a textbox so that the users can't increase the width of it? (right now they can increase it, but not decrease it, because of the `style="width: 717px;"`).

Something like:

```
<form>
<textarea maxwidth="717" />
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried max-width:717px ?

Comment: Thanks dude! Just edited my question to something similar tou your answer xD Noticed your answer after I pressed submit

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are looking for the `resize` css rule:

```
textarea {
    resize:none;
}
```

You can also set it to `vertical` or `horizontal` resize only.